# How to remove headers on all occurrences of the same Web-part list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint page where I display 15 different lists and there is one list called Links that I would like to remove the header from the first two of the three occurrences.  The code I have only removes the first occurance of the list(s) that is passed in.

On the page, I have the following include.  The code below only removes the header for the first occurrence for Links and Contacts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-lists="Links, Contacts, Links" src="../SiteAssets/js-enterprise/HideHeaders.js"></script>
```

My script is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Get a list of views to turn off the headers
    var this_js_script = $('script[src*=HideHeaders]');
    var lists = this_js_script.attr('data-lists'); 

    var str_array = lists.split(',');

    for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
       // Trim the excess whitespace.
       str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
       // Add additional code here, such as:
       //alert(str_array[i]);
       $("table[summary='"+str_array[i]+"'] tr:eq(0)").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the JavaScript code as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // Get a list of views to turn off the headers
    var this_js_script = $('script[src*=HideHeaders]');
    var lists = this_js_script.attr('data-lists'); 

    var str_array = lists.split(',');

    for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
        // Trim the excess whitespace.
        str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
        // Add additional code here, such as:
        //alert(str_array[i]);
        $("table[summary='"+str_array[i]+"']>thead").each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What if I only wanted to suppress the headers in only the first two occurrences of the web part?

Comment: We can check the "index" in $.each function, like: $.each(function(index){if(index<2){$(this).hide();}})

Comment: Yes, that works beautifully.  Obviously, I need to learn this stuff better.  TY